# Go gin: "required" binding seems not to work for nested structs

Tags: json, go-gin

I was trying to bind a nested struct from a json body using gin.
The issue I stumbled upon is that the required binding (seemingly) failed to be applied for the nested struct (`Nested` in the snippet below). However, it works fine for values of type string, int, etc, even if they are nested.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

type Nested struct {
    Hello string `json:"hello"`
}

type TransferCreateBody struct {
    TestNested    Nested `json:"nested" binding:"required"`
    TestNotNested string `json:"not_nested" binding:"required"`
}

func main() {
    g := gin.Default()
    g.POST("/hello", func(c *gin.Context) {
        var req TransferCreateBody
        if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&req); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            c.JSON(400, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
            return
        }
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{"hello": req.TestNested.Hello})
    })
    g.Run(":9000")
}
```

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:9000/hello
   -H "Content-Type: application/json"
   -d '{"not_nested": "test"}'
```

How do I make the binding work with a nested struct ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got an explanation - this behavior is due to the fact that the "required" binding is actually checked *after the json has been decoded into the target struct*.
That is, gin will check if the "required" parameter has its default (zero) value or is "properly" filled.

For a nested struct, the following would work:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

type Nested struct {
    Hello string `json:"hello"`
}

type TransferCreateBody struct {
    TestNested    *Nested `json:"nested" binding:"required"`
    TestNotNested string `json:"not_nested" binding:"required"`
}

func main() {
    g := gin.Default()
    g.POST("/hello", func(c *gin.Context) {
        var req TransferCreateBody
        if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&req); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            c.JSON(400, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
            return
        }
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{"hello": req.TestNested.Hello})
    })
    g.Run(":9000")
}
```

because the zero value of `*Nested` is `nil`, not an empty instance of `Nested`.
Another possibly confusing consequence is that the required binding will report an error if a required field is passed in the json body, but with its zero value (e.g. `{"not_nested": ""}` in the snippet above).

This can also be avoided by using pointers everywhere in the structure to bind, by using  a struct like `sql.NullXXX` to bind the values, etc.